# python-telegram-bot AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'left_chat_member'

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I do not know English, so I am writing to you with google translate. Sorry if I use the wrong word.

What I want to do with this code is to detect the member who left my telegram group and to ban automatically.
But I am getting such an error. Can you help me with this? Thanks.

```
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters
import telegram

with open("token.txt","r") as f:
    TOKEN = f.read()
    
def start(update,source):
    update.message.reply_text("Merhaba")

def handle_left_member(bot, update):
    left_user = update.left_chat_member
    bot.kickChatMember(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, user_id=left_user.id)

update = telegram.ext.Updater(TOKEN,use_context=True)
disp = update.dispatcher

disp.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler("start",start))
left_member_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.status_update.left_chat_member, handle_left_member)
disp.add_handler(left_member_handler)

update.start_polling()
update.idle()
```

The error I encountered is as follows.

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\dispatcher.py", line 557, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\handler.py", line 199, in handle_update   
    return self.callback(update, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\username\Desktop\TelegramBot\den.py", line 11, in handle_left_member
    left_user = update.left_chat_member
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'CallbackContext' object has no attribute 'left_chat_member'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have installed a version of `python-telegram-bot` between 12.0 and 13.15 but your `handle_left_member` function is written for version <=11, as it takes the arguments `bot` and `update` instead of `update` and `context`. Please see the [transition guide of v12](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0) for details.

Please note that neither of these versions are maintained anymore, only the new version v20.x is mainained.
To upgrade your code to v20, please read the [release notes](https://telegra.ph/Release-notes-for-python-telegram-bot-v200a0-05-06) and the [transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telgeram-bot`.